# Algorithm - Finding closest empty square a 2d grid

Tags: algorithm

Given a starting square (y, x) on a 2d grid, I want to find the closest empty square to it. (Note: The 4 squares adjacent to the starting square should be considered closer than the 4 diagonal squares nearest it.)

The following image shows the order that I need to check the following cells on this grid:

[image]

The grid is bounded but can be quite large. In practice, the starting coordinate will be randomly located around the grid. (So, I don't think it's too important to worry about coordinates outside the bounds of the grid....)

What algorithm can I use to iterate around the circle in this manner?

Comment: at the first look, Breadth First Search (BFS) comes to my mind

Answer (score 3):

A simple breadth-first search will do it.  Push each neighbour to be examined onto a heap, prioritised by distance.  You can probably get away with manhattan distance (dx + dy), but if not just use squared radial distance (dx<sup>2</sup> + dy<sup>2</sup>).  Whenever you pop an item it'll be the nearest.  If it's empty, you found it.  Otherwise push its neighbours onto the heap and keep popping.

I would probably use the square radial distance and only add adjacent squares (not diagonals).  The diagonals will be considered later because they are immediately adjacent to other squares.  You do need a way to keep track of which squares have already been considered so you don't add them again.  There must be a clever dynamic-programming way of tracking this without having to clear a large grid of booleans each time you search...  But saying that, a large grid of booleans will do quite nicely.

Comment: we can initialize distance array with -1 or some other negative value to keep track of the unvisited squares. This way we won't need an extra grid to keep track :)

Comment: @fallen Sure, but you still have the step of needing to clear it before a search.  It's faster to clear values that exist in a separate grid.  It need not be negative, when zero will do just fine.

Comment: what about keeping trace in a separate grid with search number for example. That whether this square has been visited in current search or not! This way we don't need to clear it as it'll be always updated when visiting that square :) suppose `isvisited[][]` is the auxiliary grid to keep trace and `isvisited[i][j]=2` and currently we're processing search number 3, so we can say in `O(1)` square(i,j) hasn't been visited and can update it in `O(1)`

Comment: Yep that sounds more along the lines of the dynamic approach I suggested would be out there.  As long as you test the search number is less than the current.  I would suggest using small datatypes like `unsigned short`, and then clearing the search grid when the current search number wraps back to zero (you'd have to skip zero and start the search number at one).

Comment: No, you've just backed down on your suggestion - don't do that.  The whole point is to use a counter instead of a boolean so that you don't have to clear for every search.  With an `unsigned short` you only need to clear the 'visited' grid every 65535 searches (that's right, not 65536 because clearing with 0 counts as a 'dummy' search).

Comment: No, you're missing a critical point: You don't search the entire grid, so you cannot make assumptions about the contents of the 'visited' flags.  However, if you know that an unvisited cell always has a value less than the current search number then you don't need to clear before each search.  Taking your search number modulo 2 and using booleans discards this important information.

Comment: +1, makes sense :) I'm cleaning up my previous comments, it has grown extra long. Thanks a lot, it was nice to discuss with you :)

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved with BFS (Breadth First Search). We have to process each square twice. First time we visit the still unvisited squares those share an edge with the current square and next time we visit the squares those share at least a point with the current square(Diagonally adjacent squares)

We can use two different queues to ensure that before processing a square 2nd time all squares with equal distance from the source to the current square have been processed at least once. :-)

Average Runtime: O(V*8) => O(V). Where V is the number of square inside the grid

Answer (score 2):

If the content of the grid changes often, use methods described in previous answers, that is bread-first search.

If the content of your grid does changes seldom AND Manhattan distance is ok for your application, my advise is to compute the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of the binarized grid (0 if empty, 1 else) distance transform is very simple for Manhattan distance, way more complicated for euclidian distance). This step can be done at a cost of 2*N*M (number of elements of the grid). Then, for each request, you can visit the neighborhood in a very straightforward manner, that is follow the path of min distance starting from the starting cell (like some gradient descent), it will stop at the nearest empty cell. May be really faster to search with this algorithm, as you don't look in the wrong way for an empty cell more than 1 cell far.